# CString palindrome test

Tags: c++, c-strings

My goal is to input through the command line, My code then takes the input, makes a copy and reverses that in my reverse function. Then returns the reversed palindrome as rev.

I have tried calling my reverse function inside of my strcmp(x,y == 0) functions and that was giving me issues, I've moved on to try and initialize a second char array and then copy reverse(palindrome) onto it and then compare.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstring>


using namespace std;

string reverse(string palindrome) {
    string rev;
    for (int i = 0; i < palindrome.length(); i++)
    rev += palindrome[palindrome.length() - 1 - i];

    return rev;
}//string reverse closing





int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char palindrome[1000] = "";     //empty string
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        strcat_s(palindrome, 1000, argv[i]);
    }


    char rev[1000] = "";
    strcpy(rev, reverse(palindrome));

    if (strcmp(palindrome, rev == 0)){
        cout << "The input was a valid palindrome";
    }
    else if (strcmp(palindrome, rev != 0)) {
        cout << "This input was not a valid palindrome";
    }

}// Main closing bracket
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `std::string` and `std::equal` with a reverse iterator? `std::string input = std::accumulate(argv, argv + argc, std::string{}); bool palindrome = std::equal(input.begin(), input.end(), input.rbegin());`

Comment: Note: you only need to reverse the latter half of the string and then compare it against the first half. Faster to not bother with the reverse and compare the beginning of the string with the end of the string and march inwards to the middle.

Comment: `CString` is a class in Microsoft's MFC and ATL libraries.

Comment: What? Do not mix C++ `string` operations with C string manipulation like `strcpy` and `strcmp`.  `rev` is an array, and so `rev == 0` is always `false`. That is not an appropriate argument for `strcmp`.

Comment: We can directly test whether a string is a palindrome: just compare whether its first half is equal to its second half in reverse:  that is `s[0]` is `s[len-1]`, `s[1]` is `s[len-2]` and so on, until the indices meet in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

It may be far easier just to use `==` to compare between the original and an initialized `std::string` initialized with a reverse iterator, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        std::string s(argv[i]);

        if (s == std::string (s.rbegin(), s.rend()))
            std::cout << s << " is a palindrome\n";
        else
            std::cout << s << " is NOT a palindrome\n";
    }
}
```

That breaks the actual reversal and compare down to a simple:

```
if (s == std::string (s.rbegin(), s.rend()))
```

See: [std::basic_string::rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and [std::basic_string::rend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/palindromeargv "anna" "bananna" "amanaplanacanalpanama"
anna is a palindrome
bananna is NOT a palindrome
amanaplanacanalpanama is a palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not better to check index by index?

```
while(true){
if(palindrome[i]!=palindrome[j];
return false;
}
```

ofc i starts from begining and j from lenght. If the number is odd it should check it with itself

Comment: I'd change the `while(true) to `while (j > i)`. No sense continuing after that because you've already compared everything in the first half to the proposed duplicate in the second half. `if(palindrome[i]!=palindrome[j];` should be `if(palindrome[i++]!=palindrome[j--])` to converge the indexes and fix up a nasty typo.

Comment: Yeah u are right, should have wrote it like that but I got a minute in bathroom while watching over my friend so I decided to paste it :')